# gfortran linker argument for library containing IEEE_GET_ROUNDING_MODE

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to write a simple Fortran library for interval arithmetic as an exercise. I want to explicitly set the rounding mode, do some work,  and then restore the rounding mode to what it was originally. However, I can't figure out which library needs to be linked to resulting executable when compiling with `gfortran`, `gcc`'s Fortran frontend.

```
! get_rounding_mode.f03
! print the rounding mode

program get_rounding_mode
  f = IEEE_GET_ROUNDING_MODE()
  print *,f
end program get_rounding_mode
```

Trying the Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work gives me

```
gfortran get_rounding_mode.f03 
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTLaxeN.o: in function `MAIN__':
get_rounding_mode.f03:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `ieee_get_rounding_mode_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Exit 1
```

By looking everywhere for `ieee_get_rounding` I found it, but I don't know how to direct `gfortran` to link it since it appears to already be in `libgfortran` .

```
find /usr/ -exec nm --print-file-name '{}' '+' 2>&1 | grep 'ieee_get_rounding'
/usr/lib/libgfortran.so.5:000000000023edc0 T __ieee_arithmetic_MOD_ieee_get_rounding_mode
/usr/lib/libgfortran.so:000000000023edc0 T __ieee_arithmetic_MOD_ieee_get_rounding_mode
```

Comment: Did you remind to `use` the corresponding [ieee modules](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/IEEE-modules.html)?

Comment: If I `use IEEE_ARITHMETIC`, the error changes to ``Unexpected use of subroutine name 'ieee_get_rounding_mode’ at (1)`` ... which I think means I'm using the [function]/[constant]/[macro]/[whatever kind of entity `IEEE_GET_ROUNDING_MODE` is] incorrectly.

Comment: I think `fegetround` in `libc` does what I want. Do you know how gfortran surfaces functions defined in `libc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IEEE_GET_ROUNDING_MODE` isn't a function.  It is a subroutine.  You need to do something like

```
program get_rounding_mode
   use ieee_arithmetic
   implicit none
   ieee_rounding_type mode
   real x
   if (ieee_support_rounding(x)) then
      call ieee_get_rounding_mode(mode)       ! Get current rounding mode
      call ieee_set_rounding_mode(IEEE_TO_UP) ! Set rounding up
      !
      ! Do your work here!
      !
      call ieee_set_rounding_mode(mode)       ! Reset rounding mode
   end if
 end program get_rounding_mode
```

Whoops, forgot the `implicit none` and declaration of `x`